# NÃO CONSIGO ALINHAR MEU SVG AO TEXTO DA MINHA LISTA

Tags: html, layout-responsivo, css

Gostaria de alinhar meu ícone SVG ao lado do meu `<li><a href="#">INFORMÁTICA</a></li>.`
Já tentei utilizar padding, margin mas os dois estão se movendo juntos pois o SVG está incluso em `<li>**<svg-aqui></svg>**(Ilustração) <a href="#">INFORMÁTICA</a></li>.`

[Demonstração do Problema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlbWc.jpg)
Como observado "INFORMÁTICA" está se desalinhando quando o ícone do controle foi colocado.
Gostaria de colocar o ícone e fazer com que ambos estejam alinhados no mesmo nível de todos os outros textos (Consoles, Suporte, Quem Somos)

Eu estou utilizando display flex e gostaria que o site continuasse responsivo mas quando coloco minha imagem meu "space-evenly" "para de funcionar"

```css
/* Parâmetros da Navegação */
nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.5rem;
    background-color: #232323;
}

li, a{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav-content li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul id="nav-content">
        
        <li><svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M29.6875 21.0938H35.9375" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
            <path d="M14.0625 21.0938H20.3125" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
            <path d="M17.1875 17.9688V24.2188" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
            <path d="M33.5973 10.8867L16.4071 10.9375C14.0193 10.9377 11.7078 11.779 9.87845 13.3137C8.0491 14.8484 6.8188 16.9784 6.40351 19.3299L6.40518 19.3302L3.209 35.7682C3.00712 36.9136 3.17564 38.0935 3.69007 39.1366C4.2045 40.1797 5.03806 41.0317 6.06968 41.5687C7.1013 42.1057 8.27727 42.2999 9.42679 42.1231C10.5763 41.9462 11.6395 41.4075 12.462 40.5852L12.4617 40.5849L20.9061 31.25L33.5973 31.1992C36.2909 31.1992 38.8742 30.1292 40.7789 28.2245C42.6836 26.3199 43.7536 23.7366 43.7536 21.043C43.7536 18.3494 42.6836 15.7661 40.7789 13.8614C38.8742 11.9567 36.2909 10.8867 33.5973 10.8867V10.8867Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
            <path d="M43.5993 19.2793L46.7928 35.7682C46.9947 36.9136 46.8262 38.0935 46.3118 39.1366C45.7973 40.1797 44.9638 41.0316 43.9322 41.5687C42.9005 42.1057 41.7246 42.2999 40.575 42.123C39.4255 41.9462 38.3623 41.4075 37.5398 40.5851L37.5402 40.5848L29.1016 31.2172" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
            </svg>
            <a href="#">INFORMÁTICA</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">CONSOLES</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">SUPORTE</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Se não entenderem o exemplo coloquem para exibir o MCVE em página toda que a pergunta fica clara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode alinhar `display: flex` no `<li>`:

```
#nav-content li{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 1.3rem;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!! Meu amigo de todas as horas, sábio, gênio